# Maven + gwt + spring + hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, gwt, maven-3

I am new with maven and gwt. I want to create a poc using maven 3, gwt 2.5.1, spring 3 and hibernate. I wanted some help in setting up the eclipse for the same.

I have installed eclipse (indigo)  and have downloaded maven plug in.  I also have downloaded gwt plugin for eclipse.
And now if I wanted to open a new gwt -maven project,  what is the artifact I have to select?  Is there any other plugin I will have to download for gluing maven and gwt?

And then how to integrate spring and hibernate to this project?

Thanks

Comment: Chechout the maven template artifacts or google for a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

For using GWT with maven , I would like to suggest [mojo gwt-maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/). And another way, check [GWT working with Maven](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WorkingWithMaven). You can integrate ***Spring*** with **GWT**  as  [Giving GWT a Spring in its Step](https://technophiliac.wordpress.com/2008/08/24/giving-gwt-a-spring-in-its-step/) .